# Magento EE - Backend, getting log out

Tags: admin, session

I'm getting this strange behavior in the backend, I'm getting log out much frequent.

1. `Session Lifetime (seconds)` is set to about 180 minute (`configuration->advanced->admin->security`)
2. `Cookie Lifetime` is set to 60 min ( `configuration->web->Session Cookie management`

What else could I check ?

- What is the full list of server configuration parameters that could be involved here ( for ex. `gc_maxlifetime` )
- Any hint how to debug this kind of issue ?

**Update**
On our staging server the issue is not present I have compared values for server configuration but everything looks same the main difference is that on live site we are using https in the backend ... could it be related ?

**Update 2**

Live server is using memcache for storing session ... I suspect this can be the issue

Comment: Is the time of the server correct?

Comment: Check your cookie lifetime in your browser (with firebug, for example) and see, if the one hour duration is set correct? Did you enter the Cookie Lifetime value in minutes, instead of seconds? Should read 3600 (60 min * 60 sec).

Comment: yes time is set in seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not following this project anymore so I'm not 100% sure about details.

I think session was managed by `Redis` or `Memcached`.
Once we reverted the session management to the default method (File/Db) the issue disappeared . ( all store run on a single server ).

So all the issue was related to a wrong MemCached (or Redis) configuration

Answer (score 6):

From experience, assuming everything in Magento is setup correctly, the issue is "session.gc_maxlifetime" in your php.ini.

Depending on your server setup, some people can alter it in the .htaccess and it works just fine. With my experience, however, I ended up needing to change it in the php.ini, and then restarting the server to get it to work.

Comment: After some investigation the issue looks to be related to memcached